# Javascript RegEx pattern to have only alphanumeric and hash(#) symbol in the middle

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate a regex pattern such the user can only type in alphanumeric with a hash symbol anywhere in between, hash(#) symbol cannot be in the beginning or the end.

This is what I have

/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$/g

Comment: can there be any number of `#` characters, or only one?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+#[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

or this if you want an optional hash symbol:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+#?[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

or this for multiple hash symbol:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9#]+[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

To check only one character (in cases # is optional):

2)   `/^[a-z0-9]+(?:#[a-z0-9]+)?$/i`

3)   `/^[a-z0-9]+(?:[a-z0-9#]+[a-z0-9]+)?$/i`

Comment: so `'a'` fits the original rules but would not match either pattern.

Comment: +1 Although if the hash is optional, you probably should allow for the case of only one alphanumeric character, you currently require 2.

Comment: well, I tried to use this, its not working - its allowing spaces. I just alphanumeric no spaces or other chars except for #

$('#Code').keyup(function() {
                if (this.value.match(/^[a-z0-9]+#[a-z0-9]+$/i)) {
                    this.value = this.value.replace(/^[a-z0-9]+#[a-z0-9]+$/i, '');
                }
            });

Comment: Also, capital letters are not being included.  (To OP, spaces aren't included here, I suspect you have a bug elsewhere.)

Comment: you could also use `\w` for alphanumeric characters. Notice, however, that this is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, and would allow the `_` underscore character. If you do not want the underscore, you should stick with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: @BlackVegetable, the `i` at the end makes it case insensitive.

Comment: Doh, I missed that.  Sorry.

Comment: @user1185775: there s a problem with your code because these patterns don't allow spaces.

Comment: @zzzzBov to correct that, you could have `/^[a-z0-9]+(#[a-z0-9]+)?$/i` instead

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte `'a'` doesn't fit any of the patterns because `+` matches one or more, so you would need 2 alphanumerics in your second solution, and 3 in the last one

Comment: Just append an OR to the end of those patterns with just one (or two) alphanumerics!

Comment: `/^([a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9#]+[a-z0-9]+)|([a-z0-9]+)$/i` is the fix you need.

Comment: Well guys, I am trying to use your answers it does not seems to be working, here what I am using this works but allows # symbol at the beginning or end which I don't want. I does not allow any spaces either
[code]
$('#Code').keyup(function() {
                if (this.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9#]+$/g)) {
                    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9#]+$/g, '');
                }
            });
[/code]

Comment: That should be placed in an edit to your question @user1185775. Also, be sure you know the difference between a `^` *in* a character class as well as *outside* one.

Comment: @BlackVegetable Yes, good point. `[^a-z0-9]` means "Not a-z or 0-9", while `^[a-z0-9]` means "a-z or 0-9 at the beginning"

Answer (score 1):

`/^[a-z0-9]+#[a-z0-9]+$/i` should do the trick.

`/^[a-z0-9]+(#[a-z0-9]+)?$/i` if the '#' is optional

`[a-z0-9]+` means one or more letter or number (the `+` means one or more)

`(#[a-z0-9]+)?` means a '#' followed by the above, but the whole thing either zero or one times (`?` means zero or one)

The `^` and `$` anchor the whole thing at the beginning and end

The `i` means case-insensitive

Thus, this will match one or more alphanum, optionally followed by a '#' and then one or more alphanums.

If you want more '#' characters, you could use `/^[a-z0-9]+([#a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9])?$/i` instead. This will match one or more alphanum, optionally followed by one or more '#' or alphanums, and then an alphanum.

You could also use `\w` for alphanumeric characters. Notice, however, that this is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, and would allow the `_` underscore character. If you do not want the underscore, you should stick with `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (or `[a-z0-9]` with the `i`)

**EDIT** saw you wanted spaces. try this (it worked with all of my tests):

```
/^[a-z0-9]+(([#a-z0-9\s]+)?[a-z0-9])?$/i
```

Note about this: It does not allow spaces at the beginning and end, but will allow consecutive spaces. It will allow optional '#' characters, and any number of them. `\s` means whitespace

Comment: This is a well written and thorough answer.  +1